# How can we reference svg file inside xsl which converts to html

Tags: html, xml, pdf, xslt, svg

I have a svg file. I need to reference this within a xsl file. Can i do that.

I will be using this xsl for html conversion.

Therefore it will like:

XSL -----> XML------> HTML

Within this XSL can I include (or reference) the existing SVG so that it appears on the HTML page

```
 <image NAME="image\Logo.svg" WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="17" />
    <xsl:template match="image">
        <object type="image/svg+xml">
               <xsl:attribute name="data"><xsl:value-of select="@NAME"/> 
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="width"><xsl:value-of select="@WIDTH"/> 
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="height"><xsl:value-of select="@HEIGHT"/> 
                </xsl:attribute>
        </object>
    </xsl:template>
```

But with this I was not getting the SVG Logo displayed on the html. Can anybody give me suggestion regarding how can i reference the svg file and get it in html

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be correct, but deducting from your presentation of it, I am tempted to assume that the organization of your files could need some tweaking.

So your transformation chain should be

> XML -----> XSLT------> HTML

instead of

> XSL -----> XML------> HTML

So I used the following layout of test files to **include the SVG** into the HTML (for optimized load time):

**Logo.svg**:

```
<svg width="400" height="180">
  <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
</svg>
```

**test.xml**:

```
<html>
    <image NAME="Logo.svg" WIDTH="20" HEIGHT="170" />
</html>
```

**test.xslt**:

```
...
<xsl:template match="/html">
  <html>
  <body>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="image">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('Logo.svg')/*" />
</xsl:template>
```

Applying an XSLT processor to test.xslt and test.xml, the **HTML** output is:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg width="400" height="180">
      <rect x="50" y="20" rx="20" ry="20" width="150" height="150" style="fill:red;stroke:black;stroke-width:5;opacity:0.5"></rect>
    Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Output is:**

[image]